# MonoDevelop - code window colour scheme

Tags: monodevelop

Is there a way to customise the code window colour scheme in MonoDevelop? I would like something like [Son Of Obsidian](http://studiostyl.es/schemes/son-of-obsidian) if that is possible.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes. Go to the MonoDevelop syntax highlighting options panel and press the "New" button:

[image: MonoDevelop syntax highlighting options]

Enter a name and description for your new colour scheme, and pick the existing colour scheme on which you would like to base it:

[image: New colour scheme]

Select your new colour scheme, and press the "Edit" button:

[image]

Now you can edit the colours of your new scheme:

[image: Colour scheme editor]

Note that you can export your scheme definition as a file using the buttons at the bottom of the syntax highlighting options panel, or import a scheme from a file. The schemes are defined using a simple XML format. However, beware that the filename must be of the form **Scheme.xml.*

Comment: Just adding something: To import a scheme from a .xml file, click the `add` button on the Syntax Highlighting panel. Spent some time looking for this and thought it would be useful to someone.